# How to use a markdown editor on JSF - Primefaces

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, markdown

Does someone knows how to use a markdown editor on JSF? I know that's possible.

I tried those stuff, but I couldn't make them to work.

http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/

http://toopay.github.io/bootstrap-markdown/

http://epiceditor.com/#step-4-init-epiceditor

I'll really appreciate if you can create a little example.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 3):

Exists already finished JSF implementation of markdown syntax based on mentioned Bootstrap Markdown in library ButterFaces. 
Just add next dependency to Maven project:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.butterfaces</groupId>
  <artifactId>components</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

And than you can use it in JSF page like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core" 
      xmlns:b="http://butterfaces.org/components"> 
<h:head /> 
<body>
    <h:form id="formId">
        <b:markdown id="input"
                    label="label"
                    hideLabel="false"
                    value="Hallo & < > "
                    tooltip="tooltip"
                    readonly="false"
                    required="false"
                    disabled="false"
                    placeholder="Enter text..."
                    language="en"
                    autoFocus="false"
                    rendered="true">
        </b:markdown>
    </h:form> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Sources of this component can be found on [GitHub](https://github.com/ButterFaces/ButterFaces/blob/master/components/src/main/java/org/butterfaces/component/html/HtmlMarkdown.java).

[Documentation](http://www.butterfaces.org/markdown.jsf)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Drenmi thanks for advice. Answer extended by code snippet.

Comment: GitHub link is broken. This one works: https://github.com/ButterFaces/ButterFaces/blob/development/components/src/main/java/org/butterfaces/component/html/HtmlMarkdown.java

Answer (score 1):

Using http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/ :

download it and add css and js Files to your JSF Header!

now assume you have a textarea in a form like this:

```
<h:form id="formID">
    <h:inputTextarea id="textAreaID" cols="10" rows="10" value="#{yourbean.textareaValue}"  >
    </h:inputTextarea>
```

then point to it via JQuery this way:

```
$('#formID\\:textAreaID').markItUp(yourSettings);
```